# Convert csv to excel in bulk

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, xlsxwriter, bulk-load

We've written a code but It doesn't work well, it just convert one column or less. This procedure receives a folder, and iterates all .csv files converting those to .xlsx

```
import csv
import glob
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pathlib import Path
import os 

def convert_csv_to_xlsx(arg1):
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    p = Path(arg1) 
    CSV_SEPARATOR = ","
    for fname in glob.glob(arg1):
        p1=Path(fname)
        if os.path.exists(fname):
            with open(fname) as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                    for c, col in enumerate(row):
                        for idx, val in enumerate(col.split(CSV_SEPARATOR)):
                            cell = sheet.cell(row=r+1, column=idx+1)
                            cell.value = val
                print('Se ha creado el archivo: ' + (str(p.parent) + str(p.root) + str(p1.stem) + ".xlsx"))
                wb.save(str(p.parent) + str(p.root) + str(p1.stem) + ".xlsx")


convert_csv_to_xlsx(r'C:\ysingh\sacoop\dscoopb\coopac-e\201812-e\*.csv')
```

Comment: Could you use pandas to load the data as a dataframe, then use it to save as excel?

Answer (score 2):

@K.CI's answer should he answer should be accepted as he apparently suggested the same thing.

Use `pandas`, the abstraction gained alone is worth the conversion. The nested loop you're using is likely the source of your issues.

Your code becomes:

```
import pandas as pd
def convert_csv_to_xlsx(arg1):
    for fname in glob.glob(arg1):
        pd.read_csv(fname).to_excel("{}.xlsx}.format(fname))
```

%timeit - shows the following for a 1MB CSV file

> 992 ms ± 48.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Works as a charm. Note that you must also import 'openpyxl' which is used by pandas.

Comment: I meant that your virtual environment must import 'openpyxl' in addition to 'pandas'.

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement of the code posted above, using f-string, Path and resulting files are x.xlsx (instead of x.csv.xlsx).

```
import sys
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


def convert_csv_to_xlsx(arg1):
    for ctr, file_name in enumerate(glob.glob(arg1), start=1):
        base_name = Path(file_name).stem
        pd.read_csv(file_name).to_excel(f"{base_name}.xlsx")
        print(f"Processed file {ctr}: '{file_name}'")


convert_csv_to_xlsx('*.csv')

sys.exit(0)
```